# It's been X days since I last saw you - should i use an inclusive or exclusive count?

Tags: meaning

Is it correct to say "I haven't seen you for 7 days" if the last time I saw you was 7 days ago?

Another example:

Is it correct to say "It's been 2 days since we last met" if I met someone on Monday and today is Wednesday?

That is, would it be normal to say "I haven't seen you for two days", or would it be better to say "I haven't seen you for 1 day" because if today is Wednesday I can still see that person, so I would not count that day. The same applies to weeks. If I met someone 7 days ago, I would say I haven't seen them for 6 days, not 7.

What would a regular English speaker say? 6 or 7? 2 or 1?

Comment: Didn't you pretty much ask this [same question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366325/hello-i-am-confused-with-days-calculation-can-someone-clarify-this-for-me) four days ago?

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/122875/ https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/138027/

Answer (score 1):

All of the above are acceptable because there is no specifically right or wrong way to address a friend in casual speech (as far as grammar at least), but I like to say, "It's been __ days since last we met/spoke." That would also be acceptable in business/professional communications.

Comment: Yeah but even if I still wanted to say it the way: I haven't seen you for ... days. Which option would you choose? Let's say the person called you on Monday, today is Wednesday. Would you say: the person hasnt called me for 1 or 2 days?

Comment: It's pretty arbitrary, but personally I would say 2 days, because I wouldn't count Monday.

Comment: would you say that as well, in case that last time somebody called you was 1 day ago, would you say he hasnt called you one day already? Let's say he called you on Monday and today is Tuesday. You would pick your phone and called him saying: hey, you didnt call me for one day?

Comment: You’d generally switch to smaller units and say, “You haven’t called me in 20 hours ( or whatever)”

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of precision that you are going to express.
If you really want to be exact then you count or keep track of the time since that moment and calculate before you speak.

Let's look at your example #2.

> Is it correct to say "It's been 2 days since we last met" if I met someone on Monday and today is Wednesday?

If you met the person at 6:00 AM on Monday and now is 1:00 AM Wednesday then the sentence can be **"It's been almost 2 days since we last met"**.

If you met the person at 6:00 AM on Monday and now is 6:00 AM Wednesday then the sentence can be **"It's been 2 days since we last met"**.

Just so you see that it is just a matter of precision in time that you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would have to be 7 days and 2 days in your examples. Really what you're doing is providing a measure of the time elapsed since the event occurred.