# Every 3 cards = after 2 or 3 cards?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

if the Joker is always 3rd card. I say there is joker every 3 cards.

Now if I want to use it with phrase after X cards.

Should I say:

> A. There is always one joker after 3 cards.
>
> B. There is always one joker after 2 cards.

So the joker arrives always after 2 or 3 cards if it is every 3 cards? Can you please explain? Thank you very much

Comment: It seems like too many of your [questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/49130/peter?tab=questions) are asking some variant of pretty much the same thing.

Comment: When counting things in a series, it doesn't matter what those things are: playing cards, days, nights, N, the principle never changes. _After_ has the same meaning in _after three days_ as in _after three cards_. After three comes four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that option B is the correct phrasing.

Say your hand is this: **card**, **card**, *Joker*. This would mean that for every three cards, the Joker is the third one (which is as you've said in your question). **Two cards** come before the joker, which means that a joker comes after **two** cards.